# Why not the easier format for the derivatives of inverse functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, soft-question, inverse

The derivatives of the inverse trig functions in almost all the textbooks or online documents  are not presented in format A, but  format B.  Are there  reasons for why we do this or is it just out of tradition?

Format A should be a much easier expression to help students link these new inverse trig formula to previous known trig ones and remember them  easily.

(A)    ($\sin^{-1}x$)' = $(\sqrt{1-x^2})^{-1}$ , ($\tan^{-1}x$)' = $({1+x^2})^{-1}$ , ($\sec^{-1}x$)' = $(|x|\sqrt{x^2-1})^{-1}$

(B)  $(\sin^{-1}x)$' = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ , $(\tan^{-1}x)$' = $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ , $(\sec^{-1}x)$' = $\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Format A  is almost identical   to that of  derivatives of trig functions $\to$

($\sin \alpha$)'= $\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$,    ($\tan \alpha$)'= $1+x^{2}$, ($\sec \alpha$)' = $|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}$

(given $\sin \alpha=x$, $\tan \alpha=x$, $\sec \alpha=x$)

Format B involves fraction expression $\frac{1}{X}$,  I  almost always need  to mentally do some conversion to link it to the above formulas from which they are derived.

Any comments welcome!

Comment: Some $40$ years of teaching experience says that students tend to be more comfortable with the fractional form than with negative exponents. And in any case it’s really the expressions $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $1+x^2$, and $|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}$, which are the same in both versions, that provide the real mnemonic link. And your notation is flawed: you mean $(\sin^{-1}x)'$, not $\sin^{-1}x'$ (and similarly for the rest).

Comment: Brian,  thanks for the background and notation correction! There is really a reason for this :-).  In that senses, we should also use $arcsinx$ rather than $sin^-1$ x ?

Comment: I don’t mind using $\sin^{-1}x$: it has a long tradition, it’s consistent with the usual notation for inverse functions, and there are times, especially when teaching the material, when one wants to emphasize that it really is an inverse function, not some completely new creation out of thin air. But I’m also comfortable using $\arcsin x$.

Comment: The problem/issue with $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is that it clashes with with the notation $\sin^n(x)$ to mean $(\sin(x))^n$ for any $n$ *except* $n=-1$ (well, for negative exponents it is a bit ambiguous too, but that’s really the problem). If we switched to $(\sin(x))^n$, there would be no conflicts/issues.

Comment: I always use arcsin myself, to avoid confusion.